# Why this safe contract(0xc059fd6dcdc0b02ee0adb7f0bb3a8d8b805962ac) source code is not verified?

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core

I saw my safe account send some txs, and this one has call a safe's contract with no source code verified, I'm confused about what this contract logic and whether it safe for use.
my tx is: https://polygonscan.com/tx/0xa3d07a705aa07d685cefb6bbbf216198db2f9a7db567fc93abf8067e90bf9b81

and the log index is 299:
[image]

So can somebody explain it and solve this thing about it? tks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

From what the transaction explorer states, it looks like address `0xD29c96cb88CD32f2C4192A63Ff45dFf3bb5c6B2f` (your safe if I am correct) created the contract `0xc059Fd6DCdC0b02EE0adb7f0bb3A8D8B805962AC`. From here it is difficult to say if this contract is dangerous; do you remember deploying (or creating a transaction in your safe to deploy) any contract in the last two years?

Thanks; Louis